# If graph G is an n-nodes Hamiltonian path, why χ(G)=2 or χ(G)=3?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, hamiltonian-path

graph $G$ is a $n$-nodes Hamiltonian path, $χ(G)$ is the least number of needed colors to make sure any two adjacent nodes not to have the same colors, then:
$$
χ(G)=\begin{cases}
2,&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
3,&\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
how could I yield this conclusion?

Comment: also, does this hold for complete graphs?

Comment: An n-node Hamiltonian path has chromatic number $2$ whenever $n\ge2$, a Hamiltonian cycle has the property you are saying

Answer (score 1):

To get you started...

Given a graph $G(V,E)$ let $H(V,E)$ be a Hamiltonial *cycle* (not just a path).

This means $H$ it essentially a "circle" of nodes. Start at any node and color it red. Then move to the next node (in either direction). That node can't be red, so color it blue. You can keep going this way, red $\rightarrow$ blue $\rightarrow$ red, etc...

Now, think about what happens with even and odd cycles.